# Multiple keys or Foreign keys in KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How can i perform 1 -> N relation in KSQL

I am having one table with bob_id as primary key, there is another table which will have multiple Rows with foo_id as primary key and bob_id as foreign key.

How can i use KSQL to replicate this situation ?

As far as i can see KSQL does not have Foreign key.

And we cannot join tables in ksql unless the column is primary key.

Repartition does not work as i am using table not streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can repartition topics as required to change the key, [see this example here](https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/inspecting-changing-topic-keys)

[Here is some good reference material](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html) on how to do different types of joins in KSQL

Comment: if i repartition the topics then the data will be lost like, i am having a 1:n relation for each key, i need that to be there so the (primary_key + repititive foreign key) must be the key..

Comment: and also can we update in streams ? [https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/inspecting-changing-topic-keys] in this they are using streams but it is retaining the data with the same primary key... is it normal ? or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: and also stream is having the create stream ...select ...partition by... But i am using tables and table is not having partition by clause, is there any way to implement 1 : n relation in KSQL

Comment: This answer is misleading, @ayshwarya is correct.  In the current docs it states explicitly that one-to-many joins are not supported : https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html#table-table-joins

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you will be able to do it in practice because I'm currently having some trouble doing something remotely [similar](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7169).

But I will explain what you should try before giving up. I really hope we both find a way to do it.

> Repartition does not work as i am using table not streams.

First of all, it's not about repartitioning, at least based on your explanation. It's about rekeying. Repartitioning would imply changing the number of partitions to align several collections(tables or streams) to be able to join them.

So, when you need to rekey, you can create a rekeyed Stream first(with `CREATE AS SELECT ... PARTITION BY`, for example), and then create a Table from that stream. It's even better that having the Table created directly from the topic because it will also be [materialized](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/materialized-views/).

And then, while 1-to-many joins are not supported, you didn't ask for them it seems. So, a `LEFT OUTER` join should do.

But that's not even the main reason I decided to answer this question. I wanted to add, because I'm myself excited about it, that Kafka Streams already [support joins by foreign keys](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-213+Support+non-key+joining+in+KTable).
And [rumor](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4424) has it, something similar for `ksqlDB` is also being worked on.